# ClassCastException with XMLRPC call to get ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem with ClassCastException - maybe you could please suggest something ? I'm trying to get response from server via XMLRPC and get a CCE.

Here`s how I call it:

```
Object[] filesList = new Object[] { 
    new Object[] {"somefile.txt", lengthOfThatFile},  
    new Object[] {"somefile2.txt", lengthOfThatFile2}
};    

ArrayList<Object[]> filesResent = (ArrayList<Object[]>) client.call("someserv.checkwhattoresend", userClientID, filesList);
```

That last line throws an exception:

```
09-11 16:14:33.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(389): java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Procedure checkwhattoresend looks like this:

```
public List<Object[]> checkwhattoresend(String userClientID, Object[] fileInfo) {
    ArrayList<Object[]> results = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
  // doing some stuff
    return results;
}
```

There should be no flaws on the server side.

**UPDATE. SOLVED AS SIMPLY AS THIS:**

```
Object[] filesResent = (Object[]) client.call("someserv.checkwhattoresend", userClientID, filesList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ljava.lang.Object; indicates an array. Are you trying to cast an Array to a List? I'm not familiar with andriod or the client.call method you have listed, but you may want to check the return type of that call with `(client.call("someserv.checkwhattoresend", userClientID, filesList)).getClass().getName()`

Comment: It shows [Ljava.lang.Object, but 
 List<Object[]> filesResent = (List<Object[]>) client.call("someserv.checkwhattoresend", userClientID, filesList);  throws exact the same exception...

Comment: Does Object[] `filesResent = client.call("someserv.checkwhattoresend", userClientID, filesList);` throw any error?

Comment: it does. But  
Object filesResent = client.call("someserv.checkwhattoresend", userClientID, filesList); 
works fine

Comment: could you please share idea why?

Comment: What's the error that it throws for Object[] filesResent = client.call(...) ? Can you also try casting, Object[] filesResent = (Object[])(client.call(...) ) ? If this works then iterate through the Object[] and .getClass() each item. This will give you a fair idea of the actual return type of someserv.checkwhattoresend.

Comment: Error is type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Object[]. Buuut Object[] with casting works fine, just let me check

Answer (score 0):

the Procedure checkwhattoresend returns

```
List<Object[]>,
```

not

```
ArrayList<Object[]>
```

Comment: List<Object[]> filesResent = (List<Object[]>) client.call("someserv.checkwhattoresend", userClientID, filesList);

throws the same exception :(

Comment: Why do you think you need to cast in that case?

Comment: because Eclipse says type mismatch (cannot do Object->List<Object>)